# Does the WordPress loop iterate through each post then stops when the current post has been found?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the WordPress loop below:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        // Display post content
    endwhile; 
endif; 
?>
```

This code checks if there are any posts in the database and then (in some way) stops when the current post is found in the database? Is this what the code does?

Answer (score 0):

This code can be used in `single-post.php` and `archive-post.php`.

On single page, `$wp_query` contain only one post, so the loop run one time.
On archive page, `$wp_query` may contain many posts, so the loop run for each.

---

PS: the select on the table is done before template are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The `loop` operates on predetermined selection of post(s). A global query is ran to determine what post(s) should be shown on a given page. A single blog post has one post in it, a category/archive would have many.

The loop doesn't care how many are selected. It just runs over the query return and outputs the result each time. It doesn't scan the entire post table each time, as that selection is done via a WP-ran SQL command before that page template is even called.